# Somar segundos, minutos e/ou horas em campo datahora

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho um campo com data e hora no Excel (coluna F) e gostaria de somar segundos, minutos e/ou horas, mas a forma utilizada, conforme na imagem exemplo abaixo, soma o valor em dias (coluna G):

[image: planilha]

---

Como faço para somar em específico os segundos, minutos e/ou horas?

Comment: Downvoter, poderia explicar o que não entendeu na pergunta? Ou se entendeu, dê a resposta, ou o motivo do seu "voto justo" e inteligente!

Comment: você não quer a diferença, né!? no caso o retorno esperado seria `15:54:47`??

Comment: @rLinhares Não... quero adicionar tipo, 2 minutos, então ficaria: `2018-11-01 07:52:10`

Comment: Transforme a data para número, você verá que ela retorna em dias. Por exemplo `2018-11-01 07:52:10` em números retorna: `43405,3278935185`. Que são 43405 dias a partir do dia `00/01/1900`. Depois você pega o resto: `0,3278935185` e multiplica por 24 e obtém as horas. E assim por diante... Com minutos e segundos. Ou utiliza uma função pronta do Excel, que é mais fácil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que o que você procura seria isso

```
=F2 + VALOR.TEMPO("02:00:00")
```

Se o seu Excel tiver em inglês só terá que ver o método equivalente.

Comment: Perfeito Matheus! Isso mesmo. Não consigo aceitar a resposta ainda, mas está resolvido! Obrigado.

Comment: De nada... Já bati muita cabeça por causa disso também. Agora existe um tempo para aceitar resposta?